# Script timeout error with Leaflet markerClusters

Tags: leaflet, geojson

Is there a better way to serve 11,000 points to a markercluster Leaflet map? Currently I receive a script timeout error. The geojson is 2megs in size. Clustering is limited to zooms <16, and the init map zoom is 10. Geojson has 3 fields: name, x_coord, y_coord.

[The map in question.](http://erichsen-group.com/demoland/NewYorkCityFilms/)

Looking for fix, method to optimize, or alternative data feed.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar problem with large geoJSON.  After some googling I found out that browser's JavaScript engine has problems parsing large geoJSON files.
What I did is I loaded geoJSON data in chunks using multiple calls. You'll have to figure out for yourself optimal chunk size.

Comment: That won't help him. If you take a look at the 50K marker example: http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.markercluster/example/marker-clustering-realworld.50000.html it runs just fine. The problem here lies in attaching 20K+ eventhandlers and about 100K of jQuery selections and on top of that there's so much more added on without thinking about the consequences, i wouldn't even know where to start.

Comment: @iH8 I'm not sure I understand your reasoning. Where did you come up with 20K+ eventhandlers and 100K jQuery selections? If you take a look at   http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.markercluster/example/marker-clustering-realworld.50000.html source you'll see that point locations (not pure geoJOSN) are are loaded in two chunks of 25000. There is obviously problem with parsing the data. Bergen88 I see you are loading geoJSON feature collection. Could you alter your code and data in the way Leaflet.markercluster example is implemented?

Comment: His 10K doesn't even come close to the 25K chunks used in that example. It should run that easily without a hitch, featurecollection or not. Those eventhandlers and selections, did you take a look at the source of the map? http://erichsen-group.com/demoland/NewYorkCityFilms/assets/js/app.js Then look at the onEachFeature methods which gets fired for every feature in the collection. I might have exaggerated (a little) with 100K but there are a lot. A quick glance i see 4 `$()`'s times 10, that's 40K of domtraversals. I'm not the least bit suprised that that doesn't run very smooth.

Comment: @iH8 Yes, you are right. onEachFeature is problematic in this case. Regarding feature collection or not - I think less is more still holds for web applications. Data will load faster if he gets rid of geoJSON serialization. I think we can conclude that Bergen88 should rewrite his code in the way marker cluster example is written.